# How can I call super inside constructor body?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int y); 
}

class Bar extends Foo { 
  int value;

  Bar(int x) { // error in this line
    value = x;
    print("Hi there");
    super(x); // error in this line
  }
}
```

How can I call `super` inside constructor body?

---

**Note:**

I know I can use initialiser list to solve it but I would like to know how to call `super` inside method body?

```
Bar(int x): value = x, super(x); // works but I am not looking for it.
```

Comment: You can't as far as I'm aware. May I ask what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I agree: You can't do that. So what are you trying to achieve which cannot be achieved by calling `super` in the initializer list?

Comment: @lrn I am from Java background, so out of curiosity I wanted to know if that could happen in dart or not.

Comment: Then the answer is correct: It cannot. You can only do the super-constructor invocation in the initializer list. The body runs entirely after the super-constructor has been called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart does not support inheriting the constructors as explicitly callable methods. The initializer list you mentioned is the supported way to call unnamed super constructors in Dart.

However, you can achieve what you want with the help of named constructors. Take a look at the below example -

```
class Foo {
  int superValue;

  Foo(); //A default zero-argument constructor

  Foo._init(this.superValue); //Named constructor

  void initValue(int x) => Foo._init(x);
}

class Bar extends Foo { 
  int value;

  Bar(int x) {
    value = x;
    print("Hi there");
    super.initValue(x);
  }
}

void main() {
  Foo foo = Bar(10); //prints 'Hi there'
}
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

You can also call the super constructor and add other statements to the child constructor using this way -

```
class Foo {
  int superValue;

  Foo(this.superValue);
}

class Bar extends Foo { 
  int value;

  Bar(int x) : super(x) {
    value = x;
    print("Hi there");
  }
}

void main() {
  Foo foo = Bar(10);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thanks. Do you have a reference for "Dart does not support inheriting the constructors as explicitly callable methods"?

Comment: Refer this documentation:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors:~:text=Constructors%20aren%E2%80%99t%20inherited